# Garbage collection and synchronized visibility

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, volatile

I have read about marking an object as volatile doesn't guarantee visibility of it's members ( **I'm not saying about thread safety just memory visibility** , quoting :

> only the object reference will be considered to be volatile by the JVM and not the object data itself which will reside on the heap

my questions :

1. The synchronize will ensure the visibility of the members (on the same lock object) in case they have been edited. Is that because **the happens-before at the end (release) of the lock** which makes the actions visible to the other thread?
2. In case of using volatile on the object, and the object reference change. what happens if the old reference is cached in one thread CPU cache? Will the GC keep it alive?

Sample code:

```
class Test{
  volatile Data data;

}

Class Data{
 int x;
 int y;
}


data= new Data(); // happens-before relationship only on creation

 //writer
 Thread writerThread = new Thread(() -> {
    data.setX(a);
    data.setY(b);
   });


 //reader
 Thread readerThread = new Thread(() -> {

  // read here is not guaranteed visibility, x,y not volatile
   int x = data.getX(); 
   int y = data.getY();          
  });
```

Comment: Regarding youre second question, objects marked as volatile are garabage collected like any other objects.

Comment: @DavidSoroko not this what I meant. I mean if the object was cached to other thread, but it's reference changed by different thread. should it be marked for delete ?

Comment: An object is either reachable or not reachable. If it is not reachable the GC will "mark" the heap memory as free and "sweep" it to the the free memory list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, `happens-before` relationship will gurantees that. While [volatile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html) keyword  also builds `happens-before` relationship between the write thread and the read thread.

> Using volatile variables reduces the risk of memory consistency
>   errors, because any write to a volatile variable establishes a
>   happens-before relationship with subsequent reads of that same
>   variable.

2. The java language specification does not mention it, or any specific mechanism about how to implement volatile. So I guess it depends on the specific JVM.

Comment: Yes the volatile has happens-before but in this case on the reference only. that's why the members doesn't have visibility right  ?

Comment: @MohammadKarmi `happens-before` does not bind with any reference. If threadA  `happens-before` threadB, it means threadB can see any variables just like threadA.

Comment: I understand.  I have edited the post with sample code. in this case you can't guaranteed the visibility of x , y. because the happens before will be done when you change the object reference `data` not x,y. hence x,y won't be the latest if they are edited after the object creation of data. right ?

Comment: @MohammadKarmi yes... I think this is more about `atomic`, the reader thread reference `data` first, then access `x` and `y`. These actions are not atomic, so volatile does not gurantee `x` and `y`'s visibility. The synchronized key word does it, only when you access `data` and `x` both in the `syncronized` block.

Comment: I have edited the post further more with full code , isn't this visibility not atomic ? because one thread read and the other writes. when reading x,y I can't get them from memory they may be cached and not latest.